# Ajax submit doesn't work (can't read $_POST in php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit my form using Ajax. When the button is clicked the **hit()** function gets called and **passes** the contents of the **textbox** back to **test.php**

`$_POST` seems to be empty, since I get the alert from ajax (form was submitted) but I don't get to see the echo (`echo $_POST['textbox']`)

**test.php**

```
<?php
    echo "test";
    if($_POST)
    {
        echo $_POST['textbox'];
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" align="center" id="form" name="form">

                <script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js"> </script>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" name="input" oninput="check();">
                <input type="button" class="form-control" id="send" name="send" value="Send" onclick="hit();">
            </form>
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

**test2.js**

```
function hit() {
        var inputText = $("#input").val();
        var inputTextString = "textbox=" + inputText;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: inputTextString,
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: @Taplar Edited. Changed the names so it's easier for you guys to read.

Comment: I mean, easy to read isn't the biggest concern.  Accuracy to what you are actually doing at the moment kinda is, :)

Comment: you mean you make the request from the same file which you've your form in?? .. anyway .. use  `data: {textbox : inputText}` instead of `data: inputTextString`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef As you can see I make the request from test2.js

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I changed that, but still, cannot see the echo

Comment: you never test if you see the `echo` - hence you don't alert the response from php (which would live here: `success: function (response) { alert( response); }`)

Comment: Why don't you use $('#form').on("submit", function(event){  });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're more of problems here

In **test.php**

- how can you include your js file before you include jquery .. first is first ..
  ***After Tested*** Yes you can use jquery `$()` inside a function without getting `$ undefined` error while you'll run the function after include jquery .. sorry my bad
- Scripts should be on the `<head></head>` or before `</body>`
- while you using just button click why you're using `<form>`

your code should be something like that

```
<?php
    echo "test";
    if($_POST)
    {
        echo $_POST['textbox'];
        return false;
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" name="input" oninput="check();">
          <input type="button" class="form-control" id="send" name="send" value="Send" onclick="hit();">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js"> </script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

On **test2.js**

```
function hit() {
    var inputText = $("#input").val();
    var inputTextString = {textbox : inputText}; // use this
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: inputTextString,
        success: function () {
           alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });
}
```

Note: for me I prefer to use separated php file to use it with ajax .. it'll make it easier for outputs

If you need to use a form .. you can use your form code *including my notes above* and make your submit button type="submit" and remove `onclick="hit()"` from it then on your js file you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // to prevent form reload
        var inputText = $("#input").val();
        var inputTextString = {textbox : inputText}; // use this
        $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: 'test.php',
           data: inputTextString,
           success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
           }
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me. Although I don't know what the return false is for. So the html doesn't load again?

Comment: @LisaCleaver `return false` in this case that means stop run the code next of it .. so if you remove it the php output will be the whole file code .. I hope it make sense .. Have a great day :)

Comment: Returning out of the scope of a function is... *strange*.

Comment: @LisaCleaver but I think  `exit` instead of `return false;` as @Jeff said will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

you will get the desired results in the response.

```
function hit() {

        var inputText = $("#input").val();


        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: {textbox : inputText},
            success: function (res) {
              alert(res);
            }
        });

}
```

And you need to change in your test.php file.

```
<?php
    echo "test";
    if($_POST)
    {
        echo $_POST['textbox'];exit;
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js"> </script>
</head>

    <body>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" align="center" id="form" name="form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" name="input" oninput="check();">
                <input type="button" class="form-control" id="send" name="send" value="Send" onclick="hit();">
            </form>
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you never test if you see the reponse from `echo` - hence you don't alert the response from php at all.

To see what your php script returns you have to alert (or log, or do something usefull with) the passed in parameter to the success callback:

```
....
success: function (response) { 
     alert(response);
     console.log(response); 
},
....
```

Anyway you should make sure to not send additional data (like unneeded html in your case) back to ajax, but only the value/json. So in your case an `exit;` after `echo` would help.

Also follow @Mohammed-Yousef's instructions for the other issues!!